# Set shortcuts for workspace switching and windows moving

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz, workspaces

On Ubuntu 14.10, I have 18 workspaces set up in 2 rows. I would like to bind these 9x2 workspaces to

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> where n= 1, 2, 3, ...9 (the top row of my keyboard) and
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, ... <kbd>O</kbd> (the second row of my keyboard)

I can do the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> ... <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>
but can't  even assign <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

1. How to expand available commands to 9*2 = 18?
2. How to force Alt-W shortcut work?
3. How to assign 'Move window to workspace 1' to Shift+Alt+1 (not Shift+Alt+!) ?

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1. Don't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> as a lot of <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys have been reserved over the years.
2. It's a reserved keystroke for opening the window menu in applications since 1987 in the [CUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access).  It's like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>: that's close and "cannot" be re-defined.
3. This is hard-coded in Unity. Again: "cannot" be done.

Now having said this, It's open source software, so you can take a C programming course, and descend into to bowels of Ubuntu and change the code to whatever you like!  But that would take me about a month, so for a reputation 1 user, I guess 2 years...